# Are sets everywhere dense in rational numbers set?

Tags: functional-analysis, rational-numbers

I'm new in MSE and in functional analysis. Really need explanation with this topic and exercise: Is the set {${m^2}/{n^2}: m,n\in \mathbb{N}$} everywhere dense in positive rational numbers set? And is the set {${m^m}/{n^n}: m,n\in \mathbb{N}$} everywhere dense in positive rational numbers set? I thought to use here a dense set definition but maybe it isn't enough.

Comment: For the first question, draw a parabola.

Comment: For the second question, if $m>n$ then $m^m/n^n\geq(n+1)^{n+1}/n^n\geq n+1$.

Comment: The first does not intersect $(-\infty,0)$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Neither does the second (I'm assuming "$\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$" was meant).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Here positive rationals, sorry, I missed the word.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm going to assume you mean the **positive** rationals, since otherwise the answer is trivially "no" (do you see why?).*

Here are two hints:

---

Note that the first set is just the set of *positive rational squares* $\{q^2: q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ *(why?)*. Now suppose I have a $p\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$, and I want to find a positive rational square "really close" to $p$.

- Although $\sqrt{p}$ probably isn't rational (e.g. take $p=2$), there are positive rationals *really really close* to $\sqrt{p}$ *(why?)*.
- Intuitively, if $q$ is a positive rational really really close to $\sqrt{p}$, then $q^2$ should be really close to $p$. Do you see how to make this precise, and why this implies that the set of positive rational squares is dense in $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$?

Before we move on to the next part, here's a follow-up exercise: what about the set of positive rational *cubes*? Is it dense in $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$?

---

The above trick doesn't seem to work - at least, not immediately - for the second set, so it's time to play around a bit! Testing some possible choices of $m$ and $n$ **(actually do this)** should convince you that numbers of the form ${m^m\over n^n}$ are either "really big" or "really small." That kind of sparseness suggests that the set *isn't* dense. To start working your way towards a proof, suppose I have natural numbers $m<n$. What's the **biggest possible value** for ${m^m\over n^n}$? It's certainly at *most* $1$, but can you find a better bound?

- Before tackling this immediately, try some examples - $m=1,n=2$, and $m=1,n=3$, and $m=2,n=3$, and maybe a couple more until you can make a guess.
- Once you've proved that your guess is correct: what does this bound tell you about the density/non-density of the set $\{{m^m\over n^n}:m,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$? *HINT: think about what happens between this bound and $1$ ...*

Comment: So 2 of sets aren’t dense?

Comment: @Bambeil What do you think, based on the information I've given?

Comment: First dense and second no? Can you show how to do with $sqrt(p)$ in the first one because at that moment I dont undesrstand. Thanks